# Refresh Mailed-in Document in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I am having a serious brain cramp right now since I don't think I have done this in 10 years...maybe I never did but I THINK I did lol.

I have a new mail-in database.  When mail comes in, either from Lotus Notes, from an outside mail system, like gmail, or from a text message from a cell phone, I want to refresh that document so that a couple fields get set based on the SMPTOriginator that the mail is from.  I thought I would do it with an agent that runs before mail arrives, but that didn't work.  I tried after mail arrives and that also didn't work.  I need it to runn almost immediately after the document arrives because they are getting emergency responders to reply ASAP and I need these documents to refresh as they come in.

Can someone point me in the right direction...this is something that I know I have done in the past, I just can't remember.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see if you've made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just don't have the necessary rights to run the agent. In any case, when the agent is correctly placed and the mail db receives a mail, the agent is started by the server (either the Agent Manager or the Router), and if the agent isn't started there is a message in the log.nsf database. Check there.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the events you tried would have worked, but perhaps they are only for mail databases, and not mail-in databases.

Anyway, you could use the "After documents are created or modified" trigger, although that won't run immediately.  It runs about every 5 minutes, I believe.

You might also create a scheduled agent.  If the process isn't very long, you might be able to get away with it running every, say, 2 minutes.

Comment: Those events do work for any database that the router task delivers a message to, hence they do work for mail-in databases.